# How to put an onClick event on an font awesome icon in react?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to set an onClick event on a fontawesome icon but it doesnt work when I do this.

```
 <i class="fab fa-accessible-icon" onClick={this.removeItems}></i>
```

It only works when I put the onClick on p tags or h tags like this.

```
 <h1 onClick={this.removeItems}><i class="fab fa-accessible-icon"></i></h1>
```

It is not possible to set event on icon itself? Doing this the second way is causing me style errors.

Edit: I did change the class to className, my bad. but its still not working and currently im bypassing it using  around the icon and having the onClick on the span.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#classname) you can look into react docs which explains to use className instead of class.
 Also wrap your `<i>` tag in `button` tag and use `onClick()` function there.

Comment: Can you please explain why the `<i>` should be wrapped inside a `<button>` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Well it should work like below...

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fa fa-cog" onClick="console.log('Clicked')"></i>
```

If its not try to wrap your icon into a `button`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button><i class="fa fa-cog" onClick="console.log('Clicked')"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try

```
<i className="fab fa-accessible-icon" onClick={this.removeItems}></i>
```

I was able to get

```
<i onClick={doSomething}>Testing</i>
```

to handle the click event, but it was rendered as jsx (ala render() method) -- assuming you are doing likewise.

Answer (score 1):

Change class attribute to ClassName
`<i className="fab fa-accessible-icon" onClick={this.removeItems}></i>`
I think its work. check the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nh2bqu

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing JSX with HTML. The i tag you have in your code is not plain html tag it is a javascript object(read more about jsx [here](https://jsx.github.io/)). React takes care of binding the events for you, don't worry if you can't see onClick in your html.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [react-fontawesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome), you can use the FontAwesomeIcon component, and set both an id and an onClick:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon id={yourIdGoesHere} icon={faEdit}  onClick={this.editItem} />

...

editItem = event => {
  let idOfClickedIcon = event.currentTarget.id
  ...do something with the item associated with the id
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the icon component doesn't have an onClick property