# OnClick listener for icon

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I struggled to set a onclick event for the icon for a while.

```
<div className="favorite">
<i id="favorite" className="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick={this._toggleFaviriteStatus}></i>
</div>


_toggleFaviriteStatus() {
    alert("aaa")
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

When I click the icon, the call back is never called.

I followed the solution in here, but I am not sure why it does not work..
[How to put an onClick event on an font awesome icon in react?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49443181/how-to-put-an-onclick-event-on-an-font-awesome-icon-in-react/49443423)

Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you write a jsfiddle for that, it will much helpful for everyone to help

Comment: @Rashomon `i` is the i tag in html,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i  CSS Frameworks etc just used it as a convenience wrapper for it's Font Awesome icons.   And yes, for react it's `onClick` not `onclick`

Comment: More info on Event naming here -> https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: OnClick not onclick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the onclick with the `div` tag

```
<div className="favorite" onClick={this._toggleFaviriteStatus}>
  <i id="favorite" className="fa fa-star-o fa-2x"> </i>
</div>
```

Comment: It's onClick not onclick in reactjs